# What's the meaning of "て-form"思った in this case?

Tags: grammar

セクハラを**受けて思った**、社長はかっこいい ([link](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180420/k10011411371000.html?utm_int=netnewsup_contents_list-items_002) to the article)

What is the meaning conveyed by the use of the て-form of 受ける followed by 思った?

I know that titles of article have generally an unusual wording but I want to understand the logic behind this use of verbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full sentence should be セクハラを受けて、社長はかっこいいと思った。It seems like the writer would like to emphasize the sentence "社長はかっこいい". This is not a natural sentence structure that we use in daily conversation or writing. The writer deliberately omitted the connection (the reason) between these 2 things, and attract people to read the passage.

The て form here is only used to show that she セクハラを受けた and then 社長はかっこいいと思った. It is like ドアを開けて、部屋に入る. The て is used to connect 2 actions in sequence.